# Cannot Resolve Method getBody() in BufferedReader

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, bufferedreader

i want to insert data into my server using **Retrofit 2.0** i have created ApiClient and also using Fragment instead of Activity...
only one error in my program 
this is class where im getting error

```
 api.insertUser(
            etName.getText().toString(),
            etAge.getText().toString(),
            etCity.getText().toString(),
            etMob.getText().toString(),

            new Callback<Response>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Response> result, Response<Response> response) {

                    BufferedReader reader = null;

                    //An string to store output from the server
                    String output = "";

                    try {
                        //Initializing buffered reader


                        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(result.getBody().in()));

                        //Reading the output in the string
                        output = reader.readLine();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //Displaying the output as a toast
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), output, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
```

please help me where i am wrong?

Comment: Your code for Retrofit 1.x. Can you add your response model class?

Comment: You call the method `getBody()` on an object of type `Call<Response>` - are you sure this is what you intended to do since the topic says different.